# Storage of bacteria in MgCl2 at 4 degrees

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology

I have a small question to which I am unable to find a proper answer.

Will bacteria in a MgCl2 buffer (or similar solution) at +4 degrees Celsius survive storage for 1-2 days? Or will they die?

What about at -80 degrees Celsius?

I am guessing that they can be stored at -80 degress but not at +4 degrees because they will continue to be metabolically active in the latter scenario but will die as they will have no nutrients to consume.

I would be grateful for your comments and inputs.

Comment: Highly dependent on the bacterial species and the buffer composition. Unanswerable in current form. We would need the above to give a sensible answer .

Comment: Speaking generally, a cryoprotectant is usually needed when storing bacteria at -80C. Even then, it's normal to see upwards of 90% viability loss with common protectants like glycerol, PEG, and Trehalose. Some bugs will survive for days or even weeks +4C while others will almost completely die off overnight. Some bacteria can even be stored for long periods of time at room temperature with little to no change in the viable population size.